# Excel Chart not binding while exporting from c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, interop

I am doing a bulk excel export operation, In that excel i have a chart, the chart should bind based on exported data. But the data's inserted as string in excel. Its a dynamic exporting I have more than 10 sheets in one excel file, I am using one common method for all operation. So my entire data as been treated as string. I will not able to convert int because its dynamic.

```
        int rCnt;
        int cCnt;
        int rw = 0;
        int cl = 0;
                // Fill The Report Content Data Here
                rw = dtblData.Rows.Count;
                cl = dtblData.Columns.Count;
                string[,] data = new string[rw, cl];
                for (var row = 1; row <= rw; row++)
                {
                    for (var column = 1; column <= cl; column++)
                    {
                        data[row - 1, column - 1] = dtblData.Rows[row - 1][column - 1].ToString();
                    }
                }
                Excel.Range endRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rw + (startrange.Cells.Row - 1), cl + (startrange.Cells.Column - 1)];
                Excel.Range writeRange = xlWorkSheet.Range[startrange, endRange];
                writeRange.WrapText = true;
                writeRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                writeRange.Value2 = data;
                data = null;
                startrange = null;
                endRange = null;
                writeRange = null;
```

[image]

Comment: You should try Epp plus to export excel they have a far better result than interop, I as of now dont have exact solution but try with epp

Comment: @Lucifer Its a big task to change entire source to Epp plus from interop

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using array of type `string` and not `int` for the "Count" Column, one way is to use strongly typed objects (in the example it is a list of structs that represents you data object) to hold data and than populate it to the excel worksheet:

```
List<dataObj> data = new List<dataObj>();
for (var row = 1; row <= rw; row++)
{
    for (var column = 1; column <= cl; column++)
    {
        dataObj d = new dataObj();
        d.DeniedSourceIp = dtblData.Rows[row - 1]["YourColNameOfDeniedSourceIp"].ToString();
        d.Count = int.Parse(dtblData.Rows[row - 1]["YourColNameOfCount"].ToString());
        data.Add(d);
    }
}


struct dataObj
{
    public string DeniedSourceIp { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

than loop trough the range and inject the data.

also, if your datatable is strongly typed why to use array / list of objects(?) you can inject the data directly from your datatable to excel worklsheet, you dont have to use `Range` you can do that:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = "somevalue";
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i found the proper solution for this. I added below line of code after assigning data.

`writeRange.Value2 = data;
writeRange.Formula = writeRange.Formula;`

Before that i added the format i required in my excel template. i changed the number columns to Number format and date as well. Cool its worked for me.